# How to force entity update when reading from and writing to the same database using Spring Batch reader and writer?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-batch, writer, hibernate-entitymanager

A simple Spring Batch job with a reader and a writer.

**Use-case:**

1. Read all records of specific entity from DB.
2. Write all records back to DB.

**Important points:**

- It is the same DB and table.
- Read entities aren't being changed at all.

The reason for this is that a custom [`UserType`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) is implemented. It encrypts the values a moment prior to the insert ([`nullSafeSet()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html#nullSafeSet(java.sql.PreparedStatement,%20java.lang.Object,%20int))) and it is not currently possible to alter this behavior.

**Expected behavior:** Entities are updated in DB.
**Actual behavior:** Entities are NOT updated in DB.

**Further investigation** showed that the `EntityManager` does not recognize that there is a change and hence does not merge the entity.

### **Question:** How is it possible to force the `EntityManager` to write back to the DB?

I tried using the reader as [`JpaPagingItemReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.html) which supposedly flushes after reading and [`HibernateCursorItemReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/HibernateCursorItemReader.html). I also tried using [`JpaItemWriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaItemWriter.html) and [`HibernateItemWriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/HibernateItemWriter.html) as the writer but to no avail.

Comment: It looks like that implementation of your custom hibernate user type just invalid. The conversion from db type to java type and BACK from java type to db type should be reversible.

Comment: @SternK I understand and partially agree. In this case though, I am working on a huge system where things are already implemented and changing it is not an option. So I'm looking for a way to implement what is under my control.